# Why would Rose hold The Doctor's hand even though he is a complete stranger?

Tags: doctor-who

I have started re-watching the Doctor Who reboot. And in the first episode the Doctor and Rose hold hand like 10 times. They are complete strangers. Why on earth would she do that? My only thought at this point is this is a European or British thing. I spent a few months in Africa and they would randomly hold hands with people they just met but I did not hear this was the case in UK as well.

Alternatively are the writers trying to show The Doctor as someone people just trust?

Or perhaps just trying to suggest Rose's instant infatuation with him?

P.S. In case it wasn't obvious from my cultural ignorance I'm American and in America only people in a romantic relationship or pre-teen girls hold hands.

Comment: I think that is not quite common in UK either (but I am from middle Europe, maybe I am ignorant too). But Doctor Is not just a *some men*, I think it is more likely to hold his hand than with most people.

Comment: @TGar Great point I added the idea to my question.

Comment: To the Doctor, humans are like children. He has to hold their hands, otherwise they'll wander off and run out into the street or something.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh  -  or worse - get a normal life.

Comment: Every incarnation of The Doctor is a bit different. Christopher Eccleston's Doctor was rather touchy-feely compared to most incarnations. On the other extreme we have  Peter Capaldi's Doctor, who barely tolerates personal contact.

Comment: Weren't they running from something scary at the time?  Or something along those lines?

Comment: The first time yes. Understood. But the next few times and even in episode 2 they were running excitedly to something. @JoeL.

Comment: If I remember correctly the first time they did it was running from extreme danger (grabbing someones hand who can keep you safe isn't an  uncommon reaction to extreme fear: even if its a stranger). After that point the hand holding seemed more of a security thing (I feel safe with this guy and those things are still out there, so i'm sticking close to this guy - who seems to know exactly whats going on)... plus the 1st time he grabbed her hand and said 'RUN', this is the same as come with me fast and dont fall behind

Answer (score 1):

Humans are very social creatures. And when our world comes crashing down, we start to seek solace with those around us, be it a stranger it a being that only holds the guise of humanity.

Answer (score -5):

I was wondering about this as well.  He usually does it when he's leading her somewhere, and it reminds me of this pickup artist that would do this.  It worked for him most of the time, but he had a specific method to do it.  He said if it wasn't super natural and if you didn't follow the right steps it would come off as creepy or they would pull away.  It makes me think of a girl I was with in my early 20's, she wanted me to hold her hand literally the 2nd time we hung out (the first time we just met briefly) and she ended up getting with some other guy for a while before me because I wouldn't "make a move".  So I don't know how girls are nowadays, but back then apparently it was pretty normal.  Coincidentally that was in 2005 I think, which is when season 1 of doctor who came out lol.  I just realized that while typing it because I went to Iraq that year and she broke up with me.  She was also a few years younger than me and I think Rose is supposed to be like 19 so might have just been something girls at that time around that age were into...but on the show the Doctor initiates the hand-holding all the time and he's older.  Could also be the 580+ year age gap, makes him feel like she's a little kid lol.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not sure how this answers the question.  What is the in-universe or out-of-universe reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @DavidW - Obviously, they are saying that the Doctor is a pickup artist. This actually makes a lot of sense: over the course of their very long lifetime, the doctor has picked up men, women, girls, boys, non-binary people, humans, aliens, fruits, vegetables, jelly babies, fish fingers, custard, guns, swords, spoons, screwdrivers, and on at least one memorable occasion, the entire planet Earth.

Comment: "I don't know how girls are nowadays, but back then apparently it was pretty normal" — Let me just blow your mind for a second: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization